# Proof that $\mathbb{Q}(\cos (2\pi/3))$ = $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

From [this website](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups) I found the following statement:

> ... the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\cos (2\pi/3))$, which is equal to
>   $\mathbb{Q}$ itself. Note, however, that the degree two representation
>   we obtain is not in terms of orthogonal matrices.

How can I prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\cos (2\pi/3))$ = $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Note that $\cos (2\pi/3)\in\Bbb Q $.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought there was the $\sqrt{3}$ involved...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb Q(a)=\Bbb Q$ if and only if $a\in\Bbb Q$. Which means the actual question here is "is $\cos(2\pi/3)$ rational?"

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. Since it’s talking about rotational symmetries I thought it also meant $\sqrt{3}/2$...